# Changing Date in Flipclock.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with Flipclock.js I have no knowledge of Jquery and this plugin is driving me nuts.  I just need to change the date to 11/23/2014 at 6pm but I can not seem to able to figure that out.

Here is my code

```
var clock;
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Grab the current date
    var currentDate = new Date();

    // Set some date in the future. In this case, it's always Jan 1
    var futureDate  = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1);

    // Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date
    var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;

    // Instantiate a coutdown FlipClock
    clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        countdown: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Where you are setting 'futureDate' instead of adding 1 year set the finish time using:

`new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);`

[mdn documentation for date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
var clock; 
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Grab the current date 
    var currentDate = new Date(); 
    // Set some date in the future. ***change to desired date***
    //var futureDate = new Date(2014, 11, 23, 6, 0, 0); 
    var futureDate = new Date(2014, 10, 23, 18, 0, 0); //fixed as per comments
    // Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date 
    var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000; 
    // Instantiate a coutdown FlipClock 
    clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, { clockFace: 'DailyCounter', countdown: true }); 
});
```

Comment: No problem - just remember that the month is 0 based (so 11 is actually December).

Comment: 6pm is 18 hours, not 6. ;-)

Comment: You can also do `var diff = (futureDate - currentDate) / 1000` to save a bit of typing.

Comment: Apparently this answer is good enough for WotC to [use directly](http://planescape.com/)